# Windows Phone 7 Webbrowser Bing (Turn on javascript)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, webbrowser-control

Im creating a windows phone 7 application and i have a webbrowser in it set to the bing search site. 
Though when trying it out in the Emulator it says turn on javascript for bing on mobile for better experience.

How do i remove this message and activate it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `IsScriptEnabled` property on the browser control, eg in XAML:

```
<phone:WebBrowser IsScriptEnabled="true" />
```

Note this must be set before loading the page.